# How are android intents handled at runtime?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I understand that `intents` are used to start new `activities` and `services` and can contain information about these - certain UI options, etc. They can be emitted by some `activities` or apps to signal that others should begin or end, or that some change should occur.

I don't understand how these are handled by the System at runtime. Do these go to the OS, where they are relayed to the place where they are needed, or do all `Activity` instances constantly check every single `intent` that is  emitted, to see if they apply?

Also, on that note, can all `Activity` instances "listen" to all intents and if not, how is this "listening privilege" given?

Comment: There is nothing named `intentListener` in the Android SDK.

Comment: fixed. Is my mention of a "listening privilege" also a problem? I did not know how else to express that and cannot find the technical term, but I hope that helps anyone reading understand what I'm getting at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do these go to the OS, where they are relayed to the place where they are needed

Yes. After all, the majority of the time, the activity that is to be started does not presently exist.

> Also, on that note, can all Activity instances "listen" to all intents

Activities do not "listen" on any `Intents`. Activities, via the manifest, describe what `Intent` structures they are interested in, via `<intent-filter>` elements. The OS then determines the activity to handle any particular `startActivity()` call (perhaps with the help of the user, via a chooser UI) and starts that activity.